# AVFoundation AudioPlayer playing multiple Tracks?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I found playing single tracks straight forward enough with AVFoundation but after looking at apples guidelines I can't seem to get multiple tracks playing. Where am I going wrong in making this work? in the following queuePlayer is an instance of AVQueuePlayer which, as I understand it, is a subclass of AVAudioPlayer.

In viewDidLoad, First I create paths to where my .mp3 files are in the main bundle:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *mp3s = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
```

then I allocate and initialise:

```
self.queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:mp3s];
```

then from the -(IBAction)play I call the queuePlayer to play like this:

```
[self.queuePlayer play];
```

but nothing happens. It says in apples documention that I can call it to play like I would an instance of the AVAudioPlayer, so how come it doesn't play? What am I missing here?

Help appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: Hey, if my answer solved your problem then please accept it. It is not good to keep question unanswered if it's solved. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Akshit, your comment didn't solve my problem so I didn't mark it as solved. Your answer is helpful in pointing out apples sources but it doesn't explain why my attempt doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Check updated ans. if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to search from the Documents directory. (i.e your `path` array)

To get files from `NSBundle`, you need to use

```
NSArray *mp3s = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
```

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` will give you path like this -

> /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/6958D21C-C94B-4843-9EF1-70406D0CA3A3/Documents

Then you are using this path to get file from your project's `NSBundle`. That's not gonna work ever.

Try `NSLog` with `mp3` array & see yourself. The problem is not in Player code. It's your paths. Now you have to decide whether you want to get files from `Documents` directory or `Project's Bundle`.

Read here:

> A bundle is a directory with a standardized hierarchical structure
>   that holds executable code and the resources used by that code.

About documents directory (Only App - specific)

> Your app only (on a non-jailbroken device) runs in a "sandboxed"
>   environment. This means that it can only access files and directories
>   within its own contents. For example Documents and Library.

See the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28).